# Data Rate, Bandwidth and Data transfer Rate - PCIe

Tags: pcie

I was talking with my senior regarding PCIe speeds. 
I am not sure if what I was saying was right. Please correct me and help me understand.

He asked what is PCIe gen3 data rate. I said 8GT/s.

He asked me what is the bandwidth then? for x1 and x16.

How to understand this question and answer. Please help me understand the difference between bandwidth and data rate and data transfer rate

[I looked at this link but couldn't understand](https://www.trentonsystems.com/blog/pci-express-interface)

Can someone provide an explanation like deriving one after another.

And is bandwidth always told in MB/s?

[This link seems to helpful but I am not understanding](https://www.tested.com/tech/457440-theoretical-vs-actual-bandwidth-pci-express-and-thunderbolt/)

Thanks

Comment: For each Lane 8 Giga Transfers/sec, for x16 - 16*8 Gigatransfers/sec. It is raw rate. If you include encoding overhead and protocol overheads then it will be less.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain my other questions?

Answer (score 3):

The total bandwidth for PCIe depends on a number of factors.

**1** The payload size. The maximum payload size specified has implications as each payload is part of a transaction layer packet. The larger the payload size, the higher the bandwidth, *but* this can have delay implications where a lot of small payloads might be better.

**2** The line coding. PCI express version 3 uses [128b / 130b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128b/130b) encoding for a 3.125% coding overhead (which is not information). Earlier versions used the venerable [8b / 10b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding) encoding.

**3** The overhead traffic.

There are three types of overhead. Datalink layer packets (which are necessary for back pressure [flow control](https://fpgawiki.intel.com/wiki/How_Credit_Works_In_Stratix_V_PCIe_G3x1_Reference_Design) and [acknowledgement packets](https://pciexpress-datalinklayer.blogspot.com/) between link partners) and the packetisation of the transaction layer packets.

The final overhead is ordered sets, in particular the skip ordered set which prevent buffer overruns for link partners with independent clock sources.

So the bandwidth of a PCIe link is system dependent. The *raw* bandwidth ignoring overheads is just under 97% of the link rate for PCIe 3. A more typical bandwith is between 70% and 90% of the link transfer rate.

A multi-lane implementation will have identical bandwidth per lane, so it will be lane bandwidth * number of lanes as the data are striped (interleaved) across lanes.

If you know al the details of the particular system, you can calculate the bandwidth pretty closely.

See [this application note](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp350.pdf) from Xilinx.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain my other questions?

Comment: I am not able to understand these. Can you please help me with my questions,only? Please

Answer (score 1):

The peak I/O data (payload) rate for each PCIe generation is as follows:

```
Gen1: 250MB/s/lane, 4GB/s for a x16 slot.
Gen2: 500MB/s/lane, 8GB/s for a x16 slot.
Gen3: 985MB/s/lane, 15.75GB/s for a x16 slot.
```

Figure about 80% of each of those as realistic, considering protocol and software overhead.